# How to process audio(.3gp) files in android

Tags: java, android, audio, codec, android-mediacodec

I need to process an audio file in android to know if the voice is contiguous with no periods.
the audio file that I need to process it is not huge it is a very small file regarding the time and the size.
I need to know if there is any library or way to perform this , I need to know how to start.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read raw values of 3gp / AMR-NB audio format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267707/how-to-read-raw-values-of-3gp-amr-nb-audio-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite broad.

I can point out a few starting points for you:

1. [Android Media Player](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)
2. [How to access an Audio file in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291731/how-to-play-audio-file-in-android)
3. [Playing Audio in Android](http://www.intransitione.com/blog/playing-an-audio-file-with-android/)
4. [How to use .3gp Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267707/how-to-read-raw-values-of-3gp-amr-nb-audio-format)

I hope this guide you in the right direction.

Good luck!